# Having issues getting fexpect to catch the prompt

Tags: python, fabric, fexpect

I don't seem to be getting the expected workings.  I can't seem to actually catch the prompt.

Here is what I have:

```
with settings(hide('commands', 'warnings') , warn_only=True):
   prompts = expect('Are you sure you want to perform this operation? [Y/N]:', 'N')
   with expecting(prompts):
      run(sudo("/something.sh apply /some.file" , user="someuser"))
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you post the code of `something.sh`?

Comment: something.sh is actually a Blackboard patching script.  Looking at it, I see that it basically sets up it's environment then drops into a Java command line script.  I'm guessing that's why it's not working.  Can't pass the value through two steps...

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem. Try 3. below and the corrected import statement.

Comment: That did it!  I really appreciate the help and this awesome tool.  This is going to make deployments a lot faster!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code with some minor things:

1. `expecting` requires a list
2. Fabric/Fexpect sudo() and run() cannot be nested. You probably just need sudo()
3. You have to escape regexp symbols, such as `[]` with a slash `\[` or just make the 'expectation' shorter:

   ```
   prompts = []
   prompts += expect('Are you sure.*', 'N')
   with expecting(prompts):
       sudo("/something.sh apply /some.file" , user="someuser")
   ```

Also, perhaps you should not `hide('commands')`, depending on what prompt `something.sh` uses.

Comment: The fabric script is still pausing waiting for input.  Not sure what's wrong...  This is the output:      out: Performing pre-apply validation...  out: Are you sure you want to perform this operation? [Y/N]:  I've tried with and without the "out:"

Comment: Did you properly import the fexpect version of sudo? `from ilogue.fexpect import run`?

Comment: Run includes sudo, I take it?  This is what I have:  import time
from fabric.api import env,roles,settings,sudo,puts,task,hide,execute,abort,local,runs_once
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
from fabric.state import output
from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run

Comment: No, I think you should just import sudo: `from ilogue.fexpect import sudo`